# Currency converter widget

Tags: kubuntu, software-recommendation

Is there any currency converter application available that could work like a widget on a desktop?

I need this on my desktop:
https://www.google.com/search?q=usd+to+eur

It does not have to have all the currencies listed in the drop-down, the main ones would be fine - USD, EUR, GBP.

Comment: What are your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Comment: Ubuntu: 20.04 LTS; KDE Plasma

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. Launch Plasma Discover
2. Find and install the corresponding Plasma Addon (for example something like [*Foreign Currencies*](https://store.kde.org/p/1239022/)).
3. Add the Widget to Plasma.